# How do I isolate dicts from a list if the id is not found in a second list of dicts (in python)?

Tags: python

I have two lists of dicts

```
list1 = 
[
    {"name": "Maria", 
    "id": "16a", 
    }, 
    {"name": "Tania", 
    "id": "13b", 
    },
    {"name": "Steve", 
    "id": "5a", 
    }
]


list2 = 
[
    {"name": "Eric", 
    "id": "16a", 
    }, 
    {"name": "Mike", 
    "id": "7b", 
    },
    {"name": "Steve", 
    id: "57a", 
    }
]
```

I want to be able to return a list of dicts from list2, if the same id is not found in list1

For example, it should return

```
[
    {"name": "Mike", 
    "id": "7b", 
    },
    {"name": "Steve", 
    "id": "57a", 
    }
]
```

I tried a few suggestions here on stack overflow but haven't been able to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension that iterates through `list2` checking the `id` with `id`s in `list1`:

```
list1 = [
    {'name': "Maria", 
    'id': "16a", 
    }, 
    {'name': "Tania", 
    'id': "13b", 
    },
    {'name': "Steve", 
    'id': "5a", 
    }
]

list2 = [
    {'name': "Eric", 
    'id': "16a", 
    }, 
    {'name': "Mike", 
    'id': "7b", 
    },
    {'name': "Steve", 
    'id': "57a", 
    }
]

list1_ids = [y['id'] for y in list1]
result = [x for x in list2 if x['id'] not in list1_ids]
# [{'name': 'Mike', 'id': '7b'}, {'name': 'Steve', 'id': '57a'}]
```

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to mention that Vasilis G's answer is preferable in terms of performance (O(1) vs O(N)).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
list1 = [
    {"name": "Maria", 
    "id": "16a", 
    }, 
    {"name": "Tania", 
    "id": "13b", 
    },
    {"name": "Steve", 
    "id": "5a", 
    }
]


list2 = [
    {"name": "Eric", 
    "id": "16a", 
    }, 
    {"name": "Mike", 
    "id": "7b", 
    },
    {"name": "Steve", 
    "id": "57a", 
    }
]

IDs = set(value["id"] for value in list1)
output = list(filter(lambda elem: elem["id"] not in IDs, list2))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Mike', 'id': '7b'}, {'name': 'Steve', 'id': '57a'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
[d2 for d2 in list2 if d2['id'] not in [d1['id'] for d1 in list1]]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '7b', 'name': 'Mike'}, {'id': '57a', 'name': 'Steve'}]
```

Comment: Copy of answer 1